# Resume youtube-dl download for MP3s

Tags: mp3, youtube-dl

I am trying to download an entire playlist using youtube-dl, this way :

```
youtube-dl -citwx --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 320K <playlist>
```

I believe it extracts the audio without having to download the actual video.

The problem is that I want to be able to stop and resume this download, which is impossible using only these arguments. However, if I add the `-k` option, the program will download the original videos (which takes a lot longer), convert them, and keep the original files (which takes a lot more space).

Is there any way for me to resume such a transfer without having to download the actual video files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer while browsing the man page :

`--download-archive FILE    Download only videos not listed in the
                            archive file. Record the IDs of all
                            downloaded videos in it.`

`youtube-dl -citwx --download-archive progress.txt --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 320K <playlist>` is the correct command.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like there is no way. If it takes just the audio, seems like it needs to be done in one go. Maybe try writing a script that takes the file path and url as arguments, and pass those into a youtube dl script, then when that's done also deletes the video file. takes more time that way, but the space issue is gone.

Comment: I'm not sure what the script would do exactly. Since I don't have enough space to download all the videos of the channels and delete them afterwards, I would have to do them one after the other, so I'm guessing the script would take the URL, retrieve the list of videos, and pass them to youtube-dl one after the other if they haven't been downloaded yet? But then how would I retrieve said list?

Answer (score 0):

A note, --title is deprecated. The correct command should be `youtube-dl -ciwx -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" --download-archive progress.txt --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 320K <playlist>`